# Add data-id attribute to each <option> of a <select> field or change value attribute?

Tags: django

This is a website for a tattoo shop. I have an `Artist` and `Tattoo` model:

```
class Artist(models.Model):
    first_name  = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_name  = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    # etc

class Tattoo(models.Model):
    artist = models.ForeignKey(Artist, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name  = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/')
```

and a `ModelForm` designed to allow artists to filter tattoos by artist:

```
class FilterArtForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Tattoo
        fields = ['artist']

        widgets = {
            'artist': forms.Select(attrs={'id': 'filter_by_artist'}),
        }
```

This form will create the following:

```
<form>
  <label for="filter_by_artist">Artist:</label></th>
  <select name="artist" id="filter_by_artist" required>
    <option value="" selected>---------</option>
    <option value="1">Artist 1</option>
    <option value="2">Artist 2</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

I am trying to store each `Artist` objects id in their respective `<option>` field. I was thinking I would have to add something like `data-artist_id` to each one as such: `<option value="1" data-artist_id >Artist 1</option>` but I suppose I could just change the `value` attribute? Looking at it, if the `value` attribute automatically increases by 1 each time it would seem that that should always align with the `Artist`'s object id value, but it just seems like I should be more explicit to avoid future headaches(for example if an `Artist` object gets deleted and another added, I don't think these values will longer align)? Is there a way to build the field in forms.py like the following:

```
 <option value="{{artist.id}}">Artist 1</option>
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not have to do anything. By default, the value is the artist's id. Those values of the options of your select are the ids of the artists that you have registered. It is not an arbitrary numbering, they are already the id of the artist.

Comment: Had no idea, thank you